# Multisite,half the way

Tags: multisite, 404-error

I have now spend too much time on this. I am getting even more confused.

I have installed wordpress and I have made it "Multisite".
I add users and I see them on the "users"-list. Also I can make some posting/pages, I see them in the list, but I can not see them as pages. - 404, not found.

In the list of "Sites" I see f.eks a site; `127.0.0.1/testsite` but I get that 404 error trying to open it.

Also the test sites create the tables in the database. And they also have written content to those tables.

Can someone please help me with this problem?
Thanks.

Okay. 
I have this as the content of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The error say:

> The requested URL /test was not found on this server
>   Apache/2.4.27 (ubuntu) server at 127.0.0.1 port 80

Comment: It looks like you haven't setup the necessary stuff to make permalinks work, e.g. a HTAccess file if you're on Apache, or the appropriate rules if you're on Nginx. Additionally you didn't clarify if the 404 you got was a WP 404 or a server 404 page, can you confirm you've done those steps?

Comment: It definately looks like an Apache problem, are you sure mod rewrite is installed? TBH WP expertise is probably not of much help, it's Apache expertise and Apache communities that would be more helpful